# How to update a native contact photo on android?

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-contentresolver

I am working on one sample application just to insert, update and delete the native android contact. I am able to successfully insert, update and delete the contact. But the problem in updating the contact photo. Below images are the observation where the same contact having two different issue. 
[image: figure 1]
[image: figure2]

After updating the contact, first image is still displaying the old image. But where as when i view the full details i am able to view the newly updated contact image as shown in the second image. Below is the code for updating the contact image.

```
 mBitmap =getAllowedPhotoBitmap(photo);
 mBitmap = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(mBitmap, THUMBNAIL_SIZE, THUMBNAIL_SIZE);
 ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    if(mBitmap!=null){    // If an image is selected successfully
        mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG ,100, stream);
      op = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
      op.withSelection(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?" + " AND " +               ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?", new String[{String.valueOf(native_contactid), ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE});
     op.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, stream.toByteArray());
     ops.add(op.build());
}
```

What is the problem and where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a open source app that does that: https://github.com/heinrisch/Contact-Picture-Sync/blob/master/src/heinrisch/contact/picture/sync/ContactHandler.java

Answer (score 0):

this file will help you set Image for contact with Contact ID

https://github.com/heinrisch/Contact-Picture-Sync/blob/master/src/heinrisch/contact/picture/sync/ContactHandler.java

```
void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // Check for the request code, we might be usign multiple
        if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
            Uri contactUri = data.getData();                
            String[] projection = {Phone.CONTACT_ID,Phone.NUMBER,ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID,ContactsContract.Data._ID };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columcontactID = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.CONTACT_ID);
            String contactID = cursor.getString(columcontactID);

            Bitmap item = (imgBg.getVisibleRectangleBitmap());

            setContactPicture(AtWallpaperDetails.this, contactID, item);
        }
    }
}
```